# Exit the terminal and execute a command.

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal, exit

I want to exit the current terminal and execute a command. Is it possible to do?

PS:: Assume that I have made a loop `while true; do bash;done`

Answer (score 0):

You could execute it in a subshell with an appropriate trap. For example, if you wanted to execute `echo -e '\nCommand done` at the end of a `while true; do true; done`, you could use this:

```
mario@mario-K53SV:~$ (trap 'echo -e "\nCommand done"' EXIT; while true; do true; done)
```

The trap registers the command you defined on the EXIT event of the subshell. The parentheses are needed to make a subshell. Be aware that in case you want to generalize this, and put your commands in variables (e.g. `MY_COMMAND='while true; do true; done'`), you will need `eval` to execute them correctly. This example output shows exactly where it is useful (without eval, this wouldn't work):

```
mario@mario-K53SV:~$ YOUR_COMMAND="while true; do true; done"
mario@mario-K53SV:~$ EXECUTE_ON_EXIT="echo -e '\nCommand done'"
mario@mario-K53SV:~$ (trap 'eval ${EXECUTE_ON_EXIT}' EXIT; eval ${YOUR_COMMAND})
^C
Command done

mario@mario-K53SV:~$
```

Should you wish so, this can also be used to automatically close your *terminal* too, at the end of the EXIT handler command: just include `kill -s SIGHUP $$` at the end of your handler (e.g. `EXECUTE_ON_EXIT="echo -e '\nCommand done'; kill -s SIGHUP $$"`).